# How to get the index of a specific item in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, get, indexof

I fill up an `Array List` with some numbers and want to find a specific number that is in the `Array List` and get its position (the index) in my `Array List`.

Any example would be great!

for example

```
ProClon.indexOf(spro.getId(id));
```

Comment: What type of objects?

Comment: please share your code, would like to see your effort

Comment: Your tags already contain the answer...

Comment: the objects are type integer

Comment: Ifrahim: why did you ask this in the first place? your example in your question is exactly how it is done.

Comment: what is the type of ProClon

Comment: Clarified the question, fixed grammar and spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First override equals() method with the specified field. then You can use indexOf.(object)

```
class A {

    int i;

    // other fields

    public A(int i) {
       this.i = i;
    }  
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        A a = (A) o;

        return i == a.i;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }
}

List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.indexOf(new A(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

check the api of arrayList. indexOf(Object o); does exactly what you need.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

Just use method indexOf in array
    arrayName.indexOf(object)